# How to get username by using ID in sql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have got two tables .

Here is my customer name table :

```
 customers_id   name          
   5           shahaparan
```

I want to get name  from order_product table where customer_id is 5

order_product:

```
 order_id total customer_id
 1        45000 -       5
```

How can I get ?

Comment: Have you even tried to get it? Please at least attempt to do it before asking, also this is very basic SQL statement and you will find plenty of examples on this site as well as all over the internet. Please do some research.

Comment: I don't see any relation between two tables.

Comment: I have been used customer_id in order_product

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from order_product as o join customers c on o.
`customer_id` = c.customers_id where c.customer_id = 5
```